# How do I pull out only the keys from the dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a dict to not use lots of if statements, but for some reason, I cannot seem to make it work the way I want. I'm trying to pull out only the keys from the dict when the correspond to the inputted day.

Thanks in advance.

*edit: expected input/output*

| Input (Day of Week) | Output (Corresponding key) |
| --- | --- |
| 'Monday' | 12 |
| 'Tuesday' | 12 |
| 'Friday' | 12 |
| 'Wednesday' | 14 |
| 'Thursday' | 14 |
| 'Saturday' | 16 |
| 'Sunday' | 16 |

```py
day = str(input())

day_price_dict = {12: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday'], 14: ['Wednesday', 'Thursday'], 16: ['Saturday', 'Sunday']}

if day in day_price_dict:
    print(day_price_dict[day])
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add input/output samples to illustrate expected behaviour?

Comment: dict.keys() should work ... Please try to look in the similar topics before posting here.

Comment: Added the input/output samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should do what you want:

```py
# example: day = 'Tuesday'
day = str(input())

day_price_dict = {12: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday'], 14: ['Wednesday', 'Thursday'], 16: ['Saturday', 'Sunday']}

# iterate through dict keys (12, 14, 16)
for key in day_price_dict:
    # if input is in the value list, print the key
    if day in day_price_dict[key]:
        # print 12
        print(key)
```

Comment: I don't see the point. If you want a price given a day, you need a `{day: price}` dictionary.

Comment: @fsimonjetz for this specific problem, you are probably right. I answered with a way to do what OP asked: "how to pull out key from dictionary", and not **if** they should be doing it

Answer (score 1):

Your conceptualization seems off: What you want is probably a mapping from days to prices rather than vice versa, i.e.,

```py
>>> day_prices = {'Monday': 12,
                  'Tuesday': 12,
                  'Wednesday': 14,
                  'Thursday': 14,
                  'Friday': 12,
                  'Saturday': 16,
                  'Sunday': 16}

>>> day_prices["Monday"]
12
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the keys like this:

```
keys = day_price_dict.keys()
# if you want a list:
keys = list(day_price_dict.keys())
```

You can also get the value:

```
for value in day_price_dict.value():
   print(value)
```

Or both

```
for key, value in day_price_dict.items():
    print(f"key: {key} -- value: {value}")
```

Comment: NB: `list(day_price_dict.keys())` == `list(day_price_dict)`.

Comment: I was not aware of that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 list() function takes any iterable as a parameter and returns a list. In Python iterable is the object you can iterate over. You can simply use the below lines to get the list of keys.

```
day_price_dict = {12: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Friday'], 14: ['Wednesday', 'Thursday'], 16: ['Saturday', 'Sunday']}
keys_list = list(day_price_dict.keys())
print(keys_list)
```